# Wrong timestamp retrieved from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I succeeded somehow how to retrieve timestamp from firebase database but now it is showing wrong timestamp. It is displaying something like this: 01-01-1970 05:30. What is surprising is that this value is displayed for all the post. The timestamp doesnt even change.

Blog view holder:

```
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            View mview;


            public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mview = itemView;
            }

            public void setTitle(String title) {
                TextView post_title = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
                post_title.setText(title);

            }

            public void setDesp(String desp) {
                TextView post_desp = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.blog_desp);
                post_desp.setText(desp);
            }

            public void setTimestampCreated(long timestamp) {
               TextView show_ts = (TextView) mview.findViewById(blog_timestamp);
               SimpleDateFormat sfd=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm");


                Date date=new Date(timestamp);
                show_ts.setText(sfd.format(date));
            }


 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                    Blog.class,
                    R.layout.blog_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase

            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder,final Blog model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesp(model.getDesp());
                    viewHolder.setTimestampCreated(model.getTimestampCreated());
                }
            };
```

Blog.java

```
public class Blog {

    String title;
    String desp;
long timestamp;

 public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(String title, String desp, long timestamp) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desp = desp;
        this.timestamp=timestamp;
}

 public String getDesp() {
        return desp;
    }

    public void setDesp(String desp) {
        this.desp = desp;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public  long getTimestampCreated() {


            return timestamp;


    }

    public void setTimestampCreated(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

Database reference:

```
public void startPosting() {


        final DatabaseReference newPost = databaseReference.push();
 String title_val = title.getText().toString().trim();
                 String desp_val = desp.getText().toString().trim();

 newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desp").setValue(desp_val);
newPost.child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
}
```

Comment: The `timestamp` being passed into `setTimestampCreated()` is zero.  Post the code where you read the posts and call `setTimestampCreated()`.

Comment: @BobSnyder I added the code above.

Comment: Please update your post to show the entire class for Blog, not just the getters/setters.

Comment: @BobSnyder I updated the code. Let me know if u need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the getter/setter names for `timestamp` do not follow the naming conventions and are not recognized.  If you look carefully at the logcat output, you should see this warning message:

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for timestamp found on class com.xxx.Blog
```

The simplest fix may be to rename the getter/setters:

```
public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

There are other solutions, one being the [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName) annotation, but I think fixing the getter/setter names may be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `TIMESTAMP` from a Firebase database, i recomand you the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank u for responding. The problem still persists.